# Jquery 'prop' makes chrome unresponsive on large number of check boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have a web application in which there is a check box list of asp.net which contain 1000+ check boxes. There are 6 check box lists of this type on my page.I have place two buttons of 'check all'and 'uncheck all' on top of each check box list,to check and uncheck all at one click.
Here is my code

```
 $('#btnCheckAllName').click(function() {
             $('[id$=cblName] :checkbox').prop('checked', true);
        });
```

I am using jquery-1.9.1.js.
This code works well in mozilla 33.1 but when I run this code in chrome 41.0 to check all check boxes in a list it get hangs and after some time a message says to kill page.
but when I have used each loop to check all check boxes like below.

```
   $('#btnCheckAllName').click(function (e) {
            $("#HeadContent1_cblName > tbody > tr").each(function () {
                $($(this).find("input[id^=HeadContent1_cblName_]")).prop('checked', true);
            });
        });
```

It work's properly.Also If I start debugger in chrome and write alert() it comes after 2-3 minutes mean while chrome is hang.Please can any one tell me why first one is working in fire fox and not in chrome? 

Here is html

```
    <table id="HeadContent1_cblName">
        <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="HeadContent1_cblName_0" type="checkbox" value="asdf" name="ctl00$HeadContent1$cblName$0">
                    <label for="HeadContent1_cblName_0">asdf</label>
                </td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="HeadContent1_cblName_1" type="checkbox" value="asdf" name="ctl00$HeadContent1$cblName$1">
                    <label for="HeadContent1_cblName_1">asdf</label>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>

    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a feeling that the issue is not with `.prop()`, but rather with your DOM selection.

You're first selector is using a non-standard selector, so it's implemented in JavaScript. Also, you're applying `[id$=cblName]` and `:checkbox` to every element found, not just `input` elements.

So the first improvement would be:

```
//  v--or whatever   v--only inputs
$('div[id$=cblName] input:checkbox').prop('checked', true);
```

---

But to use a fully native selector, use `[type=checkbox]` instead of `:checkbox`:

```
//  v--or whatever   v--only inputs
$('div[id$=cblName] input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
// ---------------------------^-- native selector for only checkboxes
```

This also should give a boost.

---

***NOTE:***

You've not provided HTML markup, but guessing from your second code block, the `cblName` element ***is*** the `:checkbox`. That means the first selector is just wrong. It should be this instead:

```
$('input[id$=cblName]:checkbox').prop('checked', true);
```

or better:

```
$('input[id$=cblName][type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
```

Notice I removed the space before the `:checkbox`. The way you had it, you were looking for descendants of the `input`, which wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @user3517064: Yes, your first selector was incorrect. Because you put a space in there, which is the "descendant combinator", you were basically saying to look for checkboxes that are *descendants of* the `cblName` element, which doesn't make sense since the `cblName` is an input. Did you try the last line of code in my answer and did it help?

Comment: Okz.... But good news is your code works perfectly :).. Remembering my teacher words which teach me jquery in past and said that to use correct selector to fastly access specific elements of dom and your code is optimized to do this..

Comment: @user3517064: If you only want the inputs inside those `tr` elements, then I'd stick to the second version, or something similar. But you don't need the extra `$()` around the selection. Just do `$(this).find("input[id^=HeadContent1_cblName_]").prop(...`